# How addToCart function arguments, product and quantity created a object with property name product and quantity with their respective values. Explain

Tags: javascript-objects

const cart = [ ];

const addToCart = function(product, quantity) {

cart.push({product,quantity});

};

addToCart('bread', 5);

1. - //Output of above code is belwo. how? Can anyone explain about this..

   ---
2. ```
   [{"product": "bread","quantity": 5}]
   ```